# Yii: How to name a controller action, so the URL included a number

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In Yii2, by default, this kind of URL: **/foo-bar** will be translated to this action:

```
public function actionFooBar() {
    // ...
}
```

What if I want the same URL to contain a number, like this: **/foo-bar-3** ?

I tried `actionFooBar3()` and `actionFooBar_3`- no luck, 404 is thrown when I access /foo-bar-3.

Ideas?

**UPDATE:**

So, the URL threw 404 because there was a typo in it, which I failed to see after too-many hours of work. Don't be a workaholic. Also, I upvote the 3 answers below, as all seem to be valid and might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you must create new rule for routing, if you wish implement this. In Yii docs said:

> Turn the first letter in each word of the action ID into upper case

but number not have upper equivalent. If you define action name as `actionFooBar3` - this action is available from url `foo-bar3`

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me. I Can Access It. **Example**: `https://myYii2.com/foo-bar-3`

```
public function actionFooBar3() {
  echo "asd";die;
}
```

**web.php**

Check whether `enablePrettyUrl` is set to `true`;

```
'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
],
```

`Error: 404` showing means, you have set some rules for controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

[image: It works FooBar3]

```
    public function actionFooBar3()
    {
        echo "HI";
        exit;
    }
```

And yes please check you have given access rules permission in **behaviors** method of controller. Sometimes it can be a problem.